# Chart Hyperlink to Update table in same report

Tags: charts, jasper-reports

I have a single report that contains two pie charts and a table, all within the Detail pane.  I would like to be able to select a slice of either of the pie charts and have that update the data contained within the table.

For example, I have a pie chart listing the severity (High, Medium, Low) of an alert by COUNT.  There is a table containing more granular data for alerts of any severity.  I would like to click on the "Medium" pie slice and have the table update its data to show only "Medium" alert granular data.

I've read about using Hyperlinks inside of the Chart in order to load an entirely different JRXML file.  Is it possible to do this within the same report and detail pane?  I have no had much luck.

Answer (score 0):

These are some basic steps to set the hyperlink :-

1. Open Pie chart in iReport and go to Chart Data --> Details --> Section hyperlink and set the hyperlink type to ReportExecution.
2. Add Link Parameters -

   ```
   Parameter Name:-    _report 
   Expression:-        "/path of the tabular eport in jasperreport server"
   ```

Pass also severity parameter to pass value of severity when u clink on pie chart.

```
   Parameter Name :-     p_severity   
   Expression:-         $F{severity}
```

and pass remaining parameters which you are using in tabular report.

Tabular report should be there on the JasperReport server with at least one parameter p_severity.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Would the process you described be capable of performing in a single report?  Meaning, a pie chart at the top of the report being clicked would affect the data held in the table at the bottom of the report?